# How do I use floating-point arithmetic in bash?

Tags: bash, floating-point, arithmetic-expressions

I am trying to divide two image widths in a Bash script, but bash gives me `0` as the result:

```
RESULT=$(($IMG_WIDTH/$IMG2_WIDTH))
```

I did study the Bash guide and I know I should use `bc`, in all examples in internet they use `bc`. In `echo` I tried to put the same thing in my `SCALE` but it didn't work.

Here is the example I found in the tutorials:

```
echo "scale=2; ${userinput}" | bc
```

How can I get Bash to give me a float like `0.5`?

Comment: A comment for everybody trying to do floating point arithmetic in your script, ask yourself: _do I really need floating point arithmetic?_ sometimes you can really get along without. See, for example the last part of [BashFAQ/022](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022).

Comment: [It is possible to teach bash e.g. integer division with floating point results.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24431665/3776858)

Answer (score 328, accepted):

You can't. bash *only* does integers; you *must* delegate to a tool such as `bc`.

Comment: how can I delegate a tool like bc in to put the answer in RESULT variable?

Comment: so you mean like VAR=$(echo "scale=2; $(($IMG_WIDTH/$IMG2_WIDTH))" | bc)   ?

Comment: @Shevin `VAR=$(echo "scale=2; $IMG_WIDTH/$IMG2_WIDTH" | bc)` or `VAR=$(bc <<<"scale=2;$IMG_WIDTH/$IMG2_WIDTH")` without $(( )) (double parentheses) ; which is expanded by the bash before executing command

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: awk is not bash.

Comment: True, but awk is generally more likely to be already installed in the system.

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul You have the best answer here. Should really be its own answer, and accepted as the answer. This particular line was incredibly useful: VAR=$(bc <<<"scale=2;$IMG_WIDTH/$IMG2_WIDTH")

Comment: Actually [you can](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/floating-point-math-bash) but i would recommend using a dedicated tool (like `bc`, `dc`, ...).

Comment: that's such an interesting parallel to javascript that ONLY has doubles :O. That said, i wonder if anyone wrote a floating/double manipulation functions in pure bash yet. I know one non bash version could just be `($_ = eval join '',  @ARGV) && print`. so that `./app 2/3` prints `0.666666666666667`. I'm kinda amazed that my bash supports `declare -i 0x1000000000000000` being `1152921504606846976`, i'd think it was 32 bits.

Comment: You can use bash functions - no need for another tool. So `must` is not correct.

Comment: So how about an example of using bc to accomplish this?

Comment: This answer is partially wrong.  bc explicitly does __not__ support floating numbers. It has scaled fixed-point numbers. See documentation on scale=# as well as the -l  (lowercase L) option.

Comment: The answer is wrong. Bash can calculate floating point results just fine without any other programs like bc or awk: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70900148/5326767

Answer (score 296):

you can do this:

```
bc <<< 'scale=2; 100/3'
33.33
```

**UPDATE** `20130926` : you can use:

```
bc -l <<< '100/3' # saves a few hits
33.33333333333333333333
```

Comment: @AndreasSpindler Kind of an old post, but in case anyone would like to know, this can be changed by applying the scale command eg. `bc -l <<< 'scale=2; 100/3'`

Comment: Just watch out if you're hoping to get an integer for later use in bash by using scale=0.  As of v1.06.95, bc, for some reason, ignores the scale variable when the input numbers have a decimal part.  Maybe this is in the docs, but I couldn't find it.  Try:  echo $(bc -l <<< 'scale=0; 1*3.3333')

Comment: @GregBell The man page says `Unless specifically mentioned the scale of the result is the maximum scale of the expressions involved.` And there is an extra note for `/` operator: `The scale of the result is the value of the variable scale.`

Comment: Thanks @psmith. Interestingly, for / it says "the scale of the result is the value of the variable scale" but not so for multiplication.
My better examples:
`bc <<< 'scale=1; 1*3.00001'`   scale is really 5 for some reason,


`bc <<< 'scale=1; 1/3.000001'`  scale is 1.


Interestingly, dividing by 1 sets it straight:


`bc <<< 'scale=1; 1*3.00001/1'` scale is 1

Comment: Why 3 left angle brackets `<<<` for the `bc` command? I've never seen this before. What does `<<<` mean? When else is it used? UPDATE: I posted this as a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58478964/what-do-three-left-angle-brackets-mean-in-bash

Comment: Now that I've learned `<<<` is a **here string**, I've decided I like the `echo` plus pipe approach better, as it allows me to do the calculation, store it into a bash variable, then use it later, as I demonstrate in my own answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722095/how-do-i-use-floating-point-division-in-bash/58479867#58479867.

Comment: To prevent ["Syntax error: redirection unexpected"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2462317/9157799), use `echo 'scale=2; 100/3' | bc` instead of `bc <<< 'scale=2; 100/3'`

Answer (score 224):

## bash

As noted by others, `bash` does not support floating point arithmetic, although you could fake it with some fixed decimal trickery, e.g. with two decimals:

```
echo $(( 100 * 1 / 3 )) | sed -e 's/..$/.&/;t' -e 's/.$/.0&/'
```

Output:

```
.33
```

See [*Nilfred's* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35402635/1331399) for a similar but more concise approach.

## Alternatives

Besides the mentioned `bc` and `awk` alternatives there are also the following:

#### clisp

```
clisp -x '(/ 1.0 3)'
```

with cleaned up output:

```
clisp --quiet -x '(/ 1.0 3)'
```

or through `stdin`:

```
echo '(/ 1.0 3)' | clisp --quiet | tail -n1
```

#### dc

```
echo 2k 1 3 /p | dc
```

#### genius cli calculator

```
echo 1/3.0 | genius
```

#### ghostscript

```
echo 1 3 div = | gs -dNODISPLAY -dQUIET | sed -n '1s/.*>//p'
```

#### gnuplot

```
echo 'pr 1/3.' | gnuplot
```

#### Imagemagick

```
convert xc: -format '%[fx:1/3]' info:
```

or through `stdin`:

```
echo 1/3 | { convert xc: -format "%[fx:$(cat)]" info:; }
```

#### jq

```
jq -n 1/3
```

or through `stdin`:

```
echo 1/3 | jq -nf /dev/stdin
```

#### ksh

```
echo 'print $(( 1/3. ))' | ksh
```

#### lua

```
lua -e 'print(1/3)'
```

or through stdin:

```
echo 'print(1/3)' | lua
```

#### maxima

```
echo '1/3,numer;' | maxima
```

with cleaned up output:

```
echo '1/3,numer;' | maxima --quiet | sed -En '2s/[^ ]+ [^ ]+ +//p'
```

#### node

```
echo 1/3 | node -p
```

#### octave

```
echo 1/3 | octave
```

#### perl

```
echo print 1/3 | perl
```

#### php

```
php -r 'echo 1/3;'
```

or through `stdin`:

```
echo '<?php print 1/3;?>' | php
```

#### python2

```
echo print 1/3. | python2
```

#### python3

```
echo 'print(1/3)' | python3
```

#### R

```
echo 1/3 | R --no-save
```

with cleaned up output:

```
echo 1/3 | R --vanilla --quiet | sed -n '2s/.* //p'
```

#### ruby

```
echo puts 1/3.0 | ruby
```

#### units

```
units 1/3
```

with compact output:

```
units --com 1/3
```

#### wcalc

```
echo 1/3 | wcalc
```

with cleaned up output:

```
echo 1/3 | wcalc | tr -d ' ' | cut -d= -f2
```

#### zsh

```
print $(( 1/3. ))
```

or through `stdin`:

```
echo 'print $(( 1/3. ))' | zsh
```

## Other sources

[Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565) [answered a similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40787/17666) over on UL.

Comment: Great answer. I know it was posted a few years after the question but is more deserving of being the accepted answer.

Comment: If you have zsh available, then it's worth considering to write your script in zsh instead of Bash

Comment: Nice list. Especially `echo 1/3 | node -p` is short.

Comment: Nice list. Sadly, the very first `bash` approach has a flaw. If the result has less than two digits (= simulated decimal places) then `sed` won't do the replacement. Example for `1 / 50`: `echo $(( 100*1/50)) | sed 's/..$/.&/'` prints `2` instead of `0.02`.

Comment: @Socowi: indeed,  in that case a second substitution is needed, see updated version.

Comment: `puts` may be better for Ruby

Comment: It should also be heavily stressed that bc DOES NOT support floating point numbers. It uses FIXED point numbers and that's a big distinction.

Comment: I love answers like this thanks for putting together a list for every language!

Comment: I think the alternatives are not practical answer a part of "dc" or "bc" all the examples are using a heavy interpreter to make a simple operation.

Comment: Don't forget php. `php -r "system(\"bc -l <<< '1/3'\");"` LOL

Answer (score 48):

Improving a little the answer of marvin:

```
RESULT=$(awk "BEGIN {printf \"%.2f\",${IMG_WIDTH}/${IMG2_WIDTH}}")
```

bc doesn't come always as installed package.

Comment: The awk script needs an `exit` to prevent it from reading from its input stream. I also suggest using awk's `-v` flags to prevent leaning toothpick syndrome. So: `RESULT=$(awk -v dividend="${IMG_WIDTH}" -v divisor="${IMG2_WIDTH}" 'BEGIN {printf "%.2f", dividend/divisor; exit(0)}')`

Comment: A more awkish way to do this would be to read the arguments from the input stream:  `RESULT=$(awk '{printf("result= %.2f\n",$1/$2)}' <<<"  $IMG_WIDTH  $IMG2_WIDTH "`.

Comment: `bc` is part of POSIX, it is usually preinstalled.

Comment: this worked for me using git bash in windows 7 ... thanks :)

Answer (score 41):

You could use bc by the `-l` option (the L letter)

```
RESULT=$(echo "$IMG_WIDTH/$IMG2_WIDTH" | bc -l)
```

Comment: If I don't include the `-l` on my system, bc doesn't do floating point math.

Answer (score 34):

As an alternative to bc, you can use awk within your script.

For example:

```
echo "$IMG_WIDTH $IMG2_WIDTH" | awk '{printf "%.2f \n", $1/$2}'
```

In the above, " %.2f " tells the printf function to return a floating point number with two digits after the decimal place. I used echo to pipe in the variables as fields since awk operates properly on them. " $1 " and " $2 " refer to the first and second fields input into awk.

And you can store the result as some other variable using:

```
RESULT = `echo ...`
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks. This is helpful for embedded environment where bc is not present. You saved me some cross compilation time.

Answer (score 28):

Well, before float was a time where fixed decimals logic was used:

```
IMG_WIDTH=100
IMG2_WIDTH=3
RESULT=$((${IMG_WIDTH}00/$IMG2_WIDTH))
echo "${RESULT:0:-2}.${RESULT: -2}"
33.33
```

Last line is a bashim, if not using bash, try this code instead:

```
IMG_WIDTH=100
IMG2_WIDTH=3
INTEGER=$(($IMG_WIDTH/$IMG2_WIDTH))
DECIMAL=$(tail -c 3 <<< $((${IMG_WIDTH}00/$IMG2_WIDTH)))
RESULT=$INTEGER.$DECIMAL
echo $RESULT
33.33
```

The rationale behind the code is: multiply by 100 before divide to get 2 decimals.

Comment: the technical term is [Fixed-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic)

Comment: To handle tiny results (e.g. `IMG2_WIDTH=3000`) and prevent an error, add this line before the echo (in bash): `[[ ${#RESULT} -lt 2 ]] && RESULT="0$RESULT"`

Answer (score 20):

It's perfect time to try zsh, an (almost) bash superset, with many additional nice features including floating point math. Here is what your example would be like in zsh:

```
% IMG_WIDTH=1080
% IMG2_WIDTH=640
% result=$((IMG_WIDTH*1.0/IMG2_WIDTH))
% echo $result
1.6875
```

This post may help you: [bash - Worth switching to zsh for casual use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43321/worth-switching-to-zsh-for-casual-use)

Comment: I'm a huge fan of zsh and have been using it for the last 4 years, but interactive use is a good emphasis here. A script that requires zsh is usually not going to be very portable across a diverse set of machines as it's usually not standard, sadly (to be fair, maybe that's okay; OP didn't say quite how it'll be used).

Answer (score 8):

1. How to do floating point calculations in bash:

   Instead of using "[here strings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80362/what-does-mean/80368#80368)" (`<<<`) with the `bc` command, like one of the [most-upvoted examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12723330/4561887) does, here's my favorite `bc` floating point example, right from the `EXAMPLES` section of the `bc` man pages (see `man bc` for the manual pages).

   Before we begin, know that an equation for pi is: `pi = 4*atan(1)`. `a()` below is the `bc` math function for `atan()`.

   1. This is *how to store the result of a floating point calculation into a bash variable--in this case into a variable called `pi`*. Note that `scale=10` sets the number of decimal digits of precision to 10 in this case. Any decimal digits after this place are *truncated*.

      ```bash
      pi="$(echo "scale=10; 4*a(1)" | bc -l)"
      ```
   2. Now, to have a single line of code that also prints out the value of this variable, simply add the `echo` command to the end as a follow-up command, as follows. Note the *truncation* at 10 decimal places, as commanded:

      ```bash
      pi="$(echo "scale=10; 4*a(1)" | bc -l)"; echo "$pi"
      ```

      Output:

      ```
      3.1415926532
      ```
   3. Finally, let's throw in some rounding. Here we will use the `printf` function to round to 4 decimal places. Note that the `3.14159...` rounds now to `3.1416`. Since we are rounding, we no longer need to use `scale=10` to truncate to 10 decimal places, so we'll just remove that part. Here's the end solution:

      ```bash
      pi="$(printf "%.4f" $(echo "4*a(1)" | bc -l))"; echo "$pi"
      ```

      Output:

      ```
      3.1416
      ```
2. Measuring and printing run time:

   Measuring and printing a program's run time is another really great application and demo of the above techniques.

   (See also [my other answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52313/how-to-get-execution-time-of-a-script-effectively/547849#547849)).

   Here is how. Note that `dt_min` gets rounded from `0.01666666666...` to `0.017`:

   ```bash
   start="$SECONDS"; sleep 1; end="$SECONDS"; dt_sec="$(( end - start ))"; dt_min="$(printf "%.3f" "$(echo "$dt_sec/60" | bc -l)")"; echo "dt_sec = $dt_sec; dt_min = $dt_min"
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   dt_sec = 1; dt_min = 0.017
   ```

### Related:

- If you need a full floating point library in bash, that you can easily import (source), use my code here: [bash/floating_point_math.sh](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/bash/floating_point_math.sh) in my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo.

  - See also my answer about using Bash libraries here: [Detailed example: how do you write, import, use, and test libraries in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76241268/4561887)
- [my answer] [Math in bash: how to use all bash operators (`+`, `-`, `/`, `*`, `**`, `&`, `&&`, `<<`, etc.), and arithmetic expansion, in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71567705/4561887)
- [my answer] https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52313/how-to-get-execution-time-of-a-script-effectively/547849#547849
- [my question] [What do three left angle brackets (`<<<`) mean in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58478964/what-do-three-left-angle-brackets-mean-in-bash)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80362/what-does-mean/80368#80368
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/179898/how-to-round-decimals-using-bc-in-bash/574474#574474

Comment: solid answer with detailed examples and uses cases & round using printf

Comment: formatting the float w/ the usage of scale made this the most complete answer!

Answer (score 7):

If you found the variant of your preference you can also wrap it into a function.

Here I'm wrapping some bashism into a div function:

One liner:

```
function div { local _d=${3:-2}; local _n=0000000000; _n=${_n:0:$_d}; local _r=$(($1$_n/$2)); _r=${_r:0:-$_d}.${_r: -$_d}; echo $_r;}
```

Or multi line:

```
function div {
  local _d=${3:-2}
  local _n=0000000000
  _n=${_n:0:$_d}
  local _r=$(($1$_n/$2))
  _r=${_r:0:-$_d}.${_r: -$_d}
  echo $_r
}
```

Now you have the function

```
div <dividend> <divisor> [<precision=2>]
```

and use it like

```
> div 1 2
.50

> div 273 123 5
2.21951

> x=$(div 22 7)
> echo $x
3.14
```

**UPDATE**
I added a little script which provides you the basic operations with floating point numbers for bash:

Usage:

```
> add 1.2 3.45
4.65
> sub 1000 .007
999.993
> mul 1.1 7.07
7.7770
> div 10 3
3.
> div 10 3.000
3.333
```

And here the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
__op() {
        local z=00000000000000000000000000000000
        local a1=${1%.*}
        local x1=${1//./}
        local n1=$((${#x1}-${#a1}))
        local a2=${2%.*}
        local x2=${2//./}
        local n2=$((${#x2}-${#a2}))
        local n=$n1
        if (($n1 < $n2)); then
                local n=$n2
                x1=$x1${z:0:$(($n2-$n1))}
        fi
        if (($n1 > $n2)); then
                x2=$x2${z:0:$(($n1-$n2))}
        fi
        if [ "$3" == "/" ]; then
                x1=$x1${z:0:$n}
        fi
        local r=$(($x1"$3"$x2))
        local l=$((${#r}-$n))
        if [ "$3" == "*" ]; then
                l=$(($l-$n))
        fi
        echo ${r:0:$l}.${r:$l}
}
add() { __op $1 $2 + ;}
sub() { __op $1 $2 - ;}
mul() { __op $1 $2 "*" ;}
div() { __op $1 $2 / ;}
```

Comment: `local _d=${3:-2}` is simpler

Answer (score 6):

I know it's old, but too tempting. So, the answer is: you can't... but you kind of can. let's try this:

```
$IMG_WIDTH=1024
$IMG2_WIDTH=2048

$RATIO="$(( IMG_WIDTH / $IMG2_WIDTH )).$(( (IMG_WIDTH * 100 / IMG2_WIDTH) % 100 ))"
```

Like that, you get 2 digits after the point, truncated (call it rounding to the lower) in pure bash (no need to launch other processes). Of course, if you only need one digit after the point you multiply by 10 and do modulo 10.

What this does:

- first `$((...))` does integer division;
- second `$((...))` does integer division on something 100 times larger, essentially moving your 2 digits to the left of the point, then (`%`) getting you only those 2 digits by doing modulo.

**Bonus track**: `bc` version × 1000 took 1.8 seconds on my laptop, while the pure `bash` one took 0.016 seconds.

Comment: Your "solution" will not work when the result is less than 10 in the "second" part. Try with, `IMG_WIDTH=103` and `IMG2_WIDTH=100` for example.

Answer (score 5):

While you can't use floating point division in Bash you can use fixed point division.  All that you need to do is multiply your integers by a power of 10 and then divide off the integer part and use a modulo operation to get the fractional part.  Rounding as needed.

```
#!/bin/bash

n=$1
d=$2

# because of rounding this should be 10^{i+1}
# where i is the number of decimal digits wanted
i=4
P=$((10**(i+1)))
Pn=$(($P / 10))
# here we 'fix' the decimal place, divide and round tward zero
t=$(($n * $P / $d + ($n < 0 ? -5 : 5)))
# then we print the number by dividing off the interger part and
# using the modulo operator (after removing the rounding digit) to get the factional part.
printf "%d.%0${i}d\n" $(($t / $P)) $(((t < 0 ? -t : t) / 10 % $Pn))
```

Answer (score 5):

For those trying to calculate percentages with the accepted answer, but are losing precision:

If you run this:

```
echo "scale=2; (100/180) * 180" | bc
```

You get `99.00` only, which is losing precision.

If you run it this way:

```
echo "result = (100/180) * 180; scale=2; result / 1" | bc -l
```

Now you get `99.99`.

Because you're scaling only at the moment of printing.

Refer to [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217570/bc-set-number-of-digits-after-decimal-point#comment1744264_217575)

Answer (score 4):

It's not really floating point, but if you want something that sets more than one result in one invocation of bc...

```
source /dev/stdin <<<$(bc <<< '
d='$1'*3.1415926535897932384626433832795*2
print "d=",d,"\n"
a='$1'*'$1'*3.1415926535897932384626433832795
print "a=",a,"\n"
')

echo bc radius:$1 area:$a diameter:$d
```

computes the area and diameter of a circle whose radius is given in $1

Answer (score 4):

There are scenarios in wich you cannot use bc becouse it might simply not be present, like in some cut down versions of busybox or embedded systems. In any case limiting outer dependencies is always a good thing to do so you can always add zeroes to the number being divided by (numerator), that is the same as multiplying by a power of 10 (you should choose a power of 10 according to the precision you need), that will make the division output an integer number. Once you have that integer treat it as a string and position the decimal point (moving it from right to left) a number of times equal to the power of ten you multiplied the numerator by. This is a simple way of obtaining float results by using only integer numbers.

Comment: Even Busybox has Awk. Perhaps there should be a more prominent Awk answer here.

Answer (score 3):

Use calc. It's the easiest I found
example:

> calc 1+1

```
 2
```

> calc 1/10

```
 0.1
```

Answer (score 2):

** Injection-safe floating point math in bash/shell **

**Note: The focus of this answer is provide ideas for injection-safe solution to performing math in bash (or other shells).** Of course, same can be used, with minor adjustment to perform advanced string processing, etc.

Most of the solution that were by presented, construct small scriptlet on the fly, using external data (variables, files, command line, environment variables). The external input can be used to inject malicious code into the engine, many of them

Below is a comparison on using the various language to perform basic math calculation, where the result in floating point. It calculates A + B * 0.1 (as floating point).

All solution attempt avoid creating dynamic scriptlets, which are extremely hard to maintain, Instead they use static program, and pass parameters into designated variable. They will safely handle parameters with special characters - reducing the possibility of code injection. The exception is 'BC' which does not provide input/output facility

The exception is 'bc', which does not provide any input/output, all the data comes via programs in stdin, and all output goes to stdout. All calculation are executing in a sandbox, which does not allow side effect (opening files, etc.). In theory, injection safe by design!

```
A=5.2
B=4.3

# Awk: Map variable into awk
# Exit 0 (or just exit) for success, non-zero for error.
#
awk -v A="$A" -v B="$B" 'BEGIN { print A + B * 0.1 ; exit 0}'

# Perl
perl -e '($A,$B) = @ARGV ; print $A + $B * 0.1' "$A" "$B"

# Python 2
python -c 'import sys ; a = float(sys.argv[1]) ; b = float(sys.argv[2]) ; print a+b*0.1' "$A" "$B"

# Python 3
python3 -c 'import sys ; a = float(sys.argv[1]) ; b = float(sys.argv[2]) ; print(a+b*0.1)' "$A" "$B"

# BC
bc <<< "scale=1 ; $A + $B * 0.1"
```

Comment: for python3 with arbitrary arguments:  
`python3 -c 'import sys ; *a, = map(float, sys.argv[1:]) ; print(a[0] + a[1]*0.1 + a[2])' "$A" "$B"` "4200.0"  
==> 4205.63

Answer (score 2):

As others have indicated, bash does not have built-in floating-point operators.

You can *implement* floating-point in bash, even without using calculator programs like *bc* and *awk*, or any external programs for that matter.

I'm doing exactly this in my project, [shellmath](https://github.com/clarity20/shellmath), in three basic steps:

1. Break the numbers down into their integer and fractional parts
2. Use the built-in integer operators to process the parts separately while being careful about place-value and carrying
3. Recombine the results

As a teaser, I've added a demo script that calculates *e* using its Taylor series centered at x=0.

Please check it out if you have a moment. I welcome your feedback!

Comment: That sounds like an interesting exercise, but is it practical? The usual objective of preferring to do data processing tasks natively in shell script instead of with an external program is to avoid the overhead of launching a new process.  But that stands against the shell's basic slowness for many such tasks.  Under what circumstances does your shell implementation outperform `bc` (for example)?

Comment: Thanks for the question. I've added some information about this to the shellmath README. I believe it's practical because of my timing experiments, which I've captured in `timingData.txt`. First off, I've been careful to use time-efficient scripting practices (details available in the project), but I think the real key is that you can run `shellmath` without forking a subshell. `shellmath` is a family of functions that write their result to a shell variable. OTOH, since `bc` is an executable, you have to subshell it to capture the results.

Comment: Kinda cool ! I like the idea

Answer (score 2):

Bash can calculate floating point results just fine without any other programs.

Bash independently even can calculate [π](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi) to the ninth decimal place accurately.

Example:

```
calc=104348/33215

accuracy=9

calc99p9=$((10**$accuracy))*$calc
result99p9=$((calc99p9))
result=${result99p9: -${#result99p9}: -$accuracy}.${result99p9: -$accuracy}

echo Bash calculated pi to be $result
```

results in

```
Bash calculated pi to be 3.141592653
```

Comment: This fails if the answer should be in range -1 ... 0.

Comment: With calc=-104348/332150 for example I get -.314159265 as result. So it seems to be working well in the range of -1 ... 0.

Comment: I stand corrected. I'm not sure what kind of example I tried but I cannot reproduce the problem for numbers in range -1 ... 0 anymore. I guess I made some kind of typo in my original testing.

Comment: Yes! This is it!

Answer (score 1):

here is awk command:  -F = field separator == +

```
echo "2.1+3.1" |  awk -F "+" '{print ($1+$2)}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Dividend = Divisor × Quotient + Remainder

Lets just calculate the quotient and remainder.
As well as concatenate those strings in a variable.

New way valid only to log_decimal divisors:

```
function main() {
  bar=10030
  divisor=100
  # divisor=50

  quotient=$((bar / divisor))
  # remainder=$((bar - v_int * divisor))
  remainder=$((bar % divisor))
  remainder_init=$remainder

  printf "%-15s --> %s\n" "quotient" "$quotient"
  printf "%-15s --> %s\n" "remainder" "$remainder"

  cnt=0
  while :; do
    remainder=$((remainder * 10))
    aux=$((remainder / divisor))
    printf "%-15s --> %s\n" "aux" "$aux"
    [[ aux -ne 0 ]] && break
    ((cnt += 1))
    printf "%-15s --> %s\n" "remainder" "$remainder"
  done
  printf "%-15s --> %s\n" "cnt" "$cnt"
  printf "%-15s --> %s\n" "aux" "$aux"

  printf $quotient
  printf "."
  for i in $(seq 1 $cnt); do printf "0"; done
  printf $remainder_init
}
clear
main
```

Old wrong way:

```
bar=1234 \
&& divisor=1000 \
    && foo=$(printf "%s.%s" $(( bar / divisor )) $(( bar % divisor ))) \
    && printf "bar is %d miliseconds or %s seconds\n" $bar $foo
```

Output: `bar is 1234 miliseconds or 1.234 seconds`

Comment: This will compute the fractional part incorrectly. Eg. bar=103 divisor=100, which should output 1.03 instead of 1.3.

Comment: You are right @Mikko, thanks! I fixed it, but only for divisors 10,100,1000,...Actually I would just use python instead.

Answer (score 0):

how precise do you need the output to be ? if an approximation via binning is already acceptable for your use case, you can even go one step further and take advantage of POSIX exit codes [0:256) (all other integers mod'd back to that range).

eg : in gawk/nawk/mawk-1, it already gives me epoch seconds down to the integer level, but I wanted to expand that to extract near-milliseconds precision but not overly pedantic about it, i run this command in a POSIX shell

```
exit $(( 10#` gdate +%5N ` * 256 / 100000 ))
```

directly assigning a 5-digit integer representing `0.xxxxxx` output of gnu-date into 1 of 256 bins, then un-doing that `256` once awk obtains the exit code of the `system()` call, i.e. the selected bin #. I found this approach to have lower overhead than using a full getline call.

This method also directly captures the output into the POSIX exit code instead of also having an extra terminal print out.

(the shell arithmetic `auto floors it to integer` if written this way instead of * 0.0256). Putting together into an awk function, it would resemble this. The `10#` is to force base-10 to prevent posix shell interpreting "01733" as an octal number.

```
function msecs() {     # n x 2**-8 = n divided by 256

    return 2^-8 * \
           system( "exit \44\50\50 "      \
                   " 10\43\140 gdate \53"  \
                   "%5N\140 \52 " \
                   "256 \57 100000 \51\51" )
}
```

- for my own code, i apply another 0.6% haircut to account for shell-overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Let us take an example to undertsand, if u want to find average of n array elements (**Ofcourse the average will be in float/decimals**)

```
declare -a arr
echo "How many numbers you want to enter?"
read n
echo "Enter the Array Elements"
for(( i=0 ; i<$n ; i++))
do
      read array_elements
      arr[$i]="$array_elements"
done
sum=0
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
     #sum and avg
     sum=$(($sum + $i))
     #average will come in decimals
     avg=`echo $sum / $n | bc -l`
done
# Output results:
printf "Average of Array Elements %.2f:" $avg
```

So we will use "**| bc -l**" to do  floating calculations

Answer (score 0):

You can use python

```bash
RESULT=$(python -c "print($IMG_WIDTH/$IMG2_WIDTH)")
```

Answer (score 0):

I will abuse Bash parameter expansion to fix @івась тарасик's great answer, no other programs required.

```
PAD=00
IMG_WIDTH=2048
IMG2_WIDTH=2024
DECIMALS="$(( (IMG_WIDTH * 100 / IMG2_WIDTH) % 100 ))"
echo "$(( IMG_WIDTH / IMG2_WIDTH)).${PAD:${#DECIMALS}:${#PAD}}${DECIMALS}"
```

Here I am using `${parameter:offset:length}` bash parameter substitution to pad the decimals with (a) zero(s).

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html