# float numbers division bash

Tags: linux, bash, division, floating

I have read all previous post about float numbers divisions in bash but I can't solve my problem...

I have this bash script:

```
lengthseq=$(sed -e 's/^\(>\).*//' sequence.fasta | sed '1d' | tr -d "\n" | awk '{ print length }')
lengthcodons=$("$lengthseq/3" | bc -l)

echo $lengthseq
echo $lengthcodons
```

Lengthseq it's ok. echo $lengthseq prints 2275859.

If I run it in konsole:

```
echo "2275859/3" | bc -l
758619.66666666666666666666
```

It's okay too.

So I don't understant why if I try it in my script, $lengthcodons generates and error.

Comment: Could I ask you want the command `lengthseq=$(sed -e 's/^\(>\).*//' sequence.fasta | sed '1d' | tr -d "\n" | awk '{ print length }')` does? (in fact, I'd like to know if it's really doing what you're expecting).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use floating-point division in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722095/how-do-i-use-floating-point-division-in-bash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct syntax of using `bc -l` is:

```
lengthcodons=$(bc -l <<< "$lengthseq/3")
echo "$lengthcodons"
758619.66666666666666666666
```

Or with `scale=2`

```
lengthcodons=$(bc -l <<< "scale=2; $lengthseq/3")
echo "$lengthcodons"
758619.66
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `echo` in following line

```
lengthcodons=$(echo "$lengthseq/3" | bc -l)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
lengthcodons=$("$lengthseq/3" | bc -l)
```

You're executing the line `"2275859/3" | bc -l` and put the result in `lengthcodons`, your forgot the `echo`.