# Script programming and significant figures

Tags: unix, division, tcsh

I'm currently toying around with making scripts using `tcsh` and Ive noticed:
If you do division it only outputs as many significant figures as the arguments going in

i.e.  ( the numbers are the entered arguments):

```
2/4 outputs 0
4/2 outputs 2
22/2 outputs 11
1/8 outputs 0
9/2 outputs 4
```

So how does one alter this so 1/8= 0.125, 2/4 = 0.5, 9/2 = 4.5 etc??

Comment: GNU/Linux shells can only perform integer division. There are other options, however: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I get a float division in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722095/how-can-i-get-a-float-division-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

Use the arbitrary precision calculator `bc` and set scale to the precision you want:

```
 $ bc -e 'scale=10;1/8;4/5; scale=30; 1/31'
 .1250000000
 .8000000000
 .032258064516129032258064516129
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to provide the memory space that you need by requesting the DATA TYPE for your variable. If you set your answer to a variable of type char, there will be only space for one character. If you set your variable type to float, there will be memory prepared for a decimal value.

Comment: KornShell can handle decimal values, but Bourne-like shells only do integers.

Comment: Ok I figured that but how do I define a variable to be a float?

Comment: @JustinFroias What shell are you using?

Comment: @JustinFroias `tcsh` only supports integers, you'll need to use something else. [Check out this link that I put in the comments above](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks).

Comment: man bc. That will give you the tools to assign floating point types.

Comment: @MarkLeavenworth Great call. Remember, though, that `bc` is *not* shell arithmetic, it's its own language.

Comment: You could also create your own function and put it in a path for the shell, if you need something specific for some reason.