# Mathematical expression in print command in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, printf

I can't get my mistake in this command:

```
a=2
b=5
c=3
printf "%.2f\t" "'$a'+'$c'*'$b'" > ofile.txt
```

I am getting the value as 50.00. But I should get it 17.00.

How to do this when a, b, c are floating values? e.g. a=2.4, b=5.1 and c=3.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your 2nd argument to printf is interpreted as the string '2', which has an ascii value of 50.
If you want to do arithmetic, use arithmetic evaluation in bash:

```
printf "%.2f\t" "$((a+b*c))" > ofile.txt
```

Comment: using `$` inside `((...))` isn't necessary

Comment: This is not working for floating values of a or b or c. Any suggestions plz?

Comment: Sorry arithmetic in bash is integer only. For floating point values you have to use an external program such as bc. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12722107/4999056

Comment: @Jahid Correct. Well spotted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf "%.2f\t" "$(($a+$b*$c))" > yourname.txt
```