# Truncated float number as variable filename in bash

Tags: bash, filenames

I wanted to do a for loop for all files with name "r?.???.txt", where ?.??? was a float from 0.000 to 3.999. However, bash does not have integer, as far as I know... That turns into a headache...

I tried to do for tedious for loop with two variables representing the numbers before and after decimal. However, I still need to insert zeros if you have ?.00?. Therefore I will need a proper treatment of float numbers and how to store / output them.

In summary, there are two questions I face

1. doing float in bash
2. output that float as a value and pass into filename

Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with handling 2 integers? `for a in {0..3}; do for b in {000..999}; do echo "r$a.$b.txt"; done; done`.

Comment: Ya, you are right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 2 variables is a good idea.

You can keep the zero padding format with seq -f option :

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i int=3;
declare -i dec=1000;

for i in $(seq 1 $int);do
        for j in $(seq -f "%03g" 1 $dec);
                do echo r$i.$j.txt;  # or do find . -name "r$i.$j.txt";
        done;
done;
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1) For float calculations you will have to delegate the task to other programs such as bc.

For example:

`echo "scale=3;20.8/4 | bc
5.200`

For more options you can check:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76060/perform-floating-point-arithmetic-in-shell-script-variable-definitions
[How do I use floating-point division in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722095/how-can-i-get-float-division)

to find out filenames having float numbers you can use regular expressions along with `find` command:

`$touch r3.987.txt
$find . -regextype sed -regex ".*/r[0-9]\.[0-9]\{3\}.txt$"
./r3.987.txt`

regular expression type is that of sed, find . means find in current directory

- */ => to check only for filenames only and skip the leading directory structure
- [0-9] matches any digit in range 0 to 9
- \. means match a dot
- [0-9]\{3\} means [0-9]{3} to match exactly 3 digits and each digit can be in range 0-9
- and finally ending in `.txt`

as for Answer 2) you can get that float value as a string by looping through the output of the find command

```
$for filename in "$(find . -regextype sed -regex ".*/r[0-9]\.[0-9]\{3\}.txt$")"  
> do  
> echo "Filename is $filename"  
> floatValueAsString=$(echo "$filename" | egrep -o '[0-9]\.[0-9]{3}')  
> echo "Float value as string is $floatValueAsString"  
> done  
Filename is ./r3.987.txt
Float value as string is 3.987
```