# Trying to calculate radius and area of circle in BASH

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to write a basic script to calculate the radius and area of a circle, where PI=3.14, and the circumference is given. I am very very new to scripting, and I can't seem to figure this out.

```
#!/bin/bash
PI=3.14
CIRC=5
RAD=echo "((CIRC/2*PI))" | bc-l
printf "Radius: %.2f" $RAD
AREA=echo "((PI*RAD**2))" | bc-l
printf "Area: %.2f" $AREA
```

The sum of both equations are not being stored in those variables, and I have no idea why. I hope someone can help explain.

Comment: Very close. just `rad=$((cir/2*pi))`, etc. recall that `$(( ...))` performs all math evaluations and using the leading `$` indicates to print the output which can be captured in a variable assignment, i.e. `rad=$(( ))`. Good luck.

Comment: I thought you had to pipe it through bc because of the decimal value, the builtin only does integer calculations. I think?

Comment: @shellter the `(())` can't evaluate float expressions, you need to delegate a tool like `bc`. ;). Pls check [\[ this \]](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12722095/1620779) & [\[ this \]](https://www.shell-tips.com/2010/06/14/performing-math-calculation-in-bash/).

Comment: hmmm. I'm used to using ksh93. Sorry, @sjsam 's answer looks good anyway. Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter : Is ksh an exception to my above comment?

Comment: Yes, I just tried `echo $(( 9.7 * 10.1 ))` and `97.97` was returned.

Comment: @remedy : Does it **have** to be bash? Zsh and (as has been mentioned above) ksh93 allow for floating point arithmetic. I personally find Zsh also more convenient for programming and interactive use than bash; don't know much about ksh93, so I don't want to compare these.

Comment: @user1934428 Yeah, it's for my intro bash scripting class. Ill have a look into Zsh. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below script would do it :

```
#!/bin/bash
pi=3.14
circ=5
rad=$( echo "scale=2;$circ / (2 * $pi)" | bc )
printf "Radius: %.2f\n" $rad
area=$( echo "scale=2;$pi * $rad * $rad" | bc )
printf "Area: %.2f\n" $area
```

**Notes**

1. See [[ command substitution ]](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html).
2. Never use full uppercase variables in your script as they are usually reserved for the system, check [[ this ]](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_01).
3. `scale` with `bc` controls the precision, check [[ this ]](http://ss64.com/bash/bc.html).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the info. I see where I went wrong, I'm using uppercase variables because that's how my teacher wants it. XD

Comment: @remedy scale set the number of digits after the decimal point.  The manpage says it is a standard function supported by bc.Please check this link for details.

Answer (score 4):

1. Since `bc` can print strings, there's no need for `printf`.  Nor backticks or `$()`, or even some of the variables.  With `bash`, the `echo` can be replaced with `<<<`:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   PI=3.14
   CIRC=5
   bc <<< "scale=2; r=$CIRC/(2*$PI)
           print "'"Radius: ", r, "\nArea: ", '"$PI"'*(r^2), "\n"'
   ```
2. *POSIX* shell code version, using a *here document*:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   PI=3.14
   CIRC=5
   bc << snip
         scale=2; r=$CIRC/(2*$PI)
         print "Radius: ", r, "\nArea: ", $PI * (r^2), "\n"
   snip
   ```
3. Pure `bc`:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/bc -q
   pi=3.14; circ=5; scale=2; r=circ/(2*pi)
   print "Radius: ", r, "\nArea: ", pi*(r^2), "\n"
   quit
   ```

Comment: With a here document, this could be made portable to any shell. The Bash `<<<` "here string" syntax is convenient, but easily avoided. (And I don't think `bc` particularly wants or requires the newlines to be escaped.)

Comment: @tripleee, you're right, `bc` needed no escapes.  The *here document* I'd considered earlier, but then figured if I was going to do that, it might as well *all* be done in `bc`.   Fixed.