# While comparing two integers, if condition does not work correctly in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, floating-point, compare

I am new to bash scripting and am working on a script to calculate CPU usage. Currently, I am calculating the CPU usage and comparing it with a predefined threshold value. However, my if condition always seems to be evaluating as false. I would appreciate assistance in correcting my script.

```
#!/bin/bash
#checking the cpu usage
cpu_usage=$( mpstat | awk '$12 ~ /[0-9.]+/ { print 100 - $12 }')
cpu_threshold=1.00
if [ $cpu_usage > $cpu_threshold ] ; then
echo "The CPU utilization is above threshold : $cpu_usage %" 
else
echo "The CPU utilization is below threshold : $cpu_usage %" 
fi
```

Please review the bash script above, as I've attempted various approaches, but the if condition consistently produces incorrect output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Ankit: Try: changing `if [ $cpu_usage > $cpu_threshold ]` to `if [[ $cpu_usage > $cpu_threshold ]]`

Comment: I was thinking floating point operations don't work in Bash - now I realize, comparisons do work though arithmetic may not.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722095/how-do-i-use-floating-point-division-in-bash

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 can you help me with same above question with 'and' operator wither other condition of same type.   like   if [ $cpu_usage > $cpu_threshold ] and [[ $cpu_usage > $cpu_threshold ]] is it correct

Comment: @AnkitKushwaha: Why you should put AND(&&) operator for same conditions? && operator should be when you want 2 different conditions should be TRUE at sametime.

Answer (score 0):

use this to compare two float numbers

```
$cpu_usage'>'$cpu_threshold | bc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct and complete answer of my question.

```
  #! /bin/bash
    #checking the cpu usage
    cpu_usage=$( mpstat | awk '$12 ~ /[0-9.]+/ { print 100 - $12 }')
    cpu_threshold=70
    echo $cpu_usage
    echo $cpu_threshold
    if [[ $cpu_usage > $cpu_threshold ]] ; then
    echo "The CPU utilization is above threshold : $cpu_usage %" 
    else
    echo "The CPU utilization is below threshold : $cpu_usage %" 
    fi
```