# Bash - Get time difference from ffmpeg - Audio and Video merge

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, floating-point

I am building an an application using ffmpeg. In which I need to subtract start time of two files(there are only two files as input). following is my code.

```
#!/bin/bash
mkvarray=()
mkvarray_name=()
for video_name in *.mkv; do
output=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=start_time -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$video_name")
mkvarray+=($output)
mkvarray_name+=("$video_name")
done 

arraylength=${#mkvarray[@]}
for (( i=0; i<${arraylength}; i++ ));
do
  echo ${mkvarray_name[$i-1]} "------>  " ${mkvarray[$i-1]}
done

max_number=0
if [[ ${mkvarray[0]} < ${mkvarray[1]} ]]; then
  echo "first-------------"

  max_number = ${mkvarray[0]} - ${mkvarray[1]}
  echo "first " $max_number
else
   echo "second-------------"
   max_number = ${mkvarray[0]} - ${mkvarray[1]}
   echo "second " $max_number
fi

echo $max_number
```

**OUTPUT**

> $ ./ffmpeg_updated.bash RTda01986c816052106c00f417387a83ff.mkv ------>
>   2.040000 cc.mkv ------>   2.040000 RT4bafb05e1b36885c75d7d67a16f5e3b2.mkv ------>   4.086000
>   first------------- ./ffmpeg_updated.bash: line 24: max_number: command
>   not found first  0 0

from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722095/how-do-i-use-floating-point-division-in-bash) I understood that, floating point arithmetic is not possible. So Is there any suggestion to proceed from this. I am pretty much new to bash. Or is there any alternative way to get things done in ffmpeg?

Comment: As mentioned in the top answer in the question you linked to you could always use `bc` to perform the calculations.

Comment: Yes, You are correct there is no other way. I have used bc

Comment: A better answer can be found in the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46770820/merge-conference-video-and-audio-call-output-using-hstack-ffmpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**
a better answer can be found in the following link
[Merge Conference Video and Audio call output using hstack ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46770820/merge-conference-video-and-audio-call-output-using-hstack-ffmpeg)

---

As mentioned in the linked question. There is no way to do floating point arithmetic via bash directly. we have to use bc.
Updated code is given below.

> VIDEO MERGER

```
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "VIDEO MERGER"
    echo "------------"
    echo "VIDEO MERGER: started"
    mkvarray=()
    mkvarray_name=()
    #ASSIGN VIDEO START TIME TO VARIBALES
    for video_name in *.mkv; do
    start_time=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=start_time -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$video_name")
    mkvarray+=($start_time)
    mkvarray_name+=("$video_name")
    done 
    #PRINT START TIME OF VIDEO FILES (FOR DEBUG)
    #arraylength=${#mkvarray[@]}
    #for (( i=0; i<${arraylength}; i++ ));
    #do
    #  echo $i ${mkvarray_name[$i]} "------>  " ${mkvarray[$i]}
    #done

    #echo "----->" ${mkvarray_name[0]} ${mkvarray[0]}
    #echo "----->" ${mkvarray_name[1]} ${mkvarray[1]}

    #GETTING THE START TIME 
    RESULT=$(echo "scale=5; (${mkvarray[0]} - ${mkvarray[1]})" | tr -d $'\r' | bc -l)
    updated_result=0
    #check which file is  
    if (( $(echo "$RESULT < 0" |bc -l) )); then
    updated_result=$(echo "$RESULT * -1" |bc -l)
    else 
    updated_result=$RESULT
    fi

    #IDENTIFY THE FIRST FILE AND SECOND FILE IN ORDER OF START TIME
    if (( $(echo "(${mkvarray[0]} > ${mkvarray[1]})" | tr -d $'\r' |bc -l) )); then #do
    second_file=${mkvarray_name[0]}
    first_file=${mkvarray_name[1]}
    echo "FIRST FILE : " ${mkvarray_name[1]} ", TIME :" ${mkvarray[1]}
    echo "SECOND FILE : " ${mkvarray_name[0]} ", TIME :" ${mkvarray[0]}
    else
    second_file=${mkvarray_name[1]}
    first_file=${mkvarray_name[0]}
    echo "FIRST FILE : " ${mkvarray_name[0]} ", TIME :" ${mkvarray[0]}
    echo "SECOND FILE : " ${mkvarray_name[1]} ", TIME :" ${mkvarray[1]}
    fi
    echo "TIME DIFERENCE :" $updated_result

    ffmpeg -i $first_file -itsoffset $updated_result -i $second_file -filter_complex "[0]pad=iw*2:ih[int]; [int][1]overlay=W/2:0[vid]" -map [vid] -c:v libvpx -crf 23 -quality good -cpu-used 3 -an output_video.webm
    echo "VIDEO MERGER: finished"
```

> ```
>  AUDIO MERGER
> ```

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "AUDIO MERGER"
echo "------------"
echo "AUDIO MERGER : started"
mkvarray=()
mkvarray_name=()
#ASSIGN VIDEO START TIME TO VARIBALES
for video_name in *.mka; do
start_time=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=start_time -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$video_name")
mkvarray+=($start_time)
mkvarray_name+=("$video_name")
done 
#PRINT START TIME OF VIDEO FILES (FOR DEBUG)
#arraylength=${#mkvarray[@]}
#for (( i=0; i<${arraylength}; i++ ));
#do
#  echo $i ${mkvarray_name[$i]} "------>  " ${mkvarray[$i]}
#done

#echo "----->" ${mkvarray_name[0]} ${mkvarray[0]}
#echo "----->" ${mkvarray_name[1]} ${mkvarray[1]}

#GETTING THE START TIME 
RESULT=$(echo "scale=5; (${mkvarray[0]} - ${mkvarray[1]})" | tr -d $'\r' | bc -l)
updated_result=0
#check which file is  
if (( $(echo "$RESULT < 0" |bc -l) )); then
updated_result=$(echo "$RESULT * -1 * 1000" |bc -l)
else 
updated_result=$(echo "$RESULT * 1000" |bc -l)
fi

#IDENTIFY THE FIRST FILE AND SECOND FILE IN ORDER OF START TIME
if (( $(echo "(${mkvarray[0]} > ${mkvarray[1]})" | tr -d $'\r' |bc -l) )); then #do
second_file=${mkvarray_name[0]}
first_file=${mkvarray_name[1]}
echo "FIRST FILE : " ${mkvarray_name[1]} ", TIME :" ${mkvarray[1]}
echo "SECOND FILE : " ${mkvarray_name[0]} ", TIME :" ${mkvarray[0]}
else
second_file=${mkvarray_name[1]}
first_file=${mkvarray_name[0]}
echo "FIRST FILE : " ${mkvarray_name[0]} ", TIME :" ${mkvarray[0]}
echo "SECOND FILE : " ${mkvarray_name[1]} ", TIME :" ${mkvarray[1]}
fi
echo "TIME DIFERENCE :" $updated_result

ffmpeg -i $first_file -i $second_file -filter_complex "[1]adelay="$updated_result"|"$updated_result"[d];[0][d]amix=inputs=2" -strict -2 output_audio.webm
echo "AUDIO MERGER : finished"
```

> ```
> MERGE AUDIO & VIDEO
> ```

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "AUDIO/VIDEO OUTPUT MERGER"
echo "-------------------------"
echo "AUDIO/VIDEO OUTPUT MERGER : started merging audio and video"
ffmpeg -i output_video.webm -i output_audio.webm -c:v copy -c:a copy full.webm
echo "AUDIO/VIDEO OUTPUT MERGER : finished merging audio and video"
```

Comment: Added the full code, It could be helpful for someone

Comment: Link for bc in Windows : http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/bc.htm