# Merge Conference Video and Audio call output using hstack ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

having two videos and two audio files

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'first.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : GStreamer matroskamux version 1.8.1.1
    creation_time   : 2017-10-16 14:13:15
  Duration: 00:06:01.24, start: 3.817000, bitrate: 1547 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p, 640x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 16.75 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Video
Input #1, matroska,webm, from 'second.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : GStreamer matroskamux version 1.8.1.1
    creation_time   : 2017-10-16 14:13:24
  Duration: 00:05:49.79, start: 13.509000, bitrate: 810 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p, 640x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Video
Input #2, matroska,webm, from 'first.mka':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : GStreamer matroskamux version 1.8.1.1
    creation_time   : 2017-10-16 14:13:15
  Duration: 00:06:01.30, start: 3.786000, bitrate: 46 kb/s
    Stream #3:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Audio
Input #3, matroska,webm, from 'second.mka':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : GStreamer matroskamux version 1.8.1.1
    creation_time   : 2017-10-16 14:13:24
  Duration: 00:05:50.61, start: 13.498000, bitrate: 50 kb/s
    Stream #2:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Audio
```

above files are output of video conference call, want to merge all files together and show as side by side video.

start time of video and audio are different, want to sync the video and audio respectively and merge the video side by side.

Initially used the following command to merge two videos

```
ffmpeg -i first.mkv -i second.mkv -filter_complex "
[0:v]scale=320:240,pad=325:240,setsar=1[l];[1:v]scale=320:240,setsar=1[r];
[l][r]hstack" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 0 merged.mp4
```

After that use the following command to merge as suggested by @mulvya

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:09.692 -i first.mkv -i second.mkv -i first.mka -i second.mka -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=320:240,pad=325:240,setsar=1[l];[1:v]scale=320:240,setsar=1[r];[l][r]hstack=shortest=1[v];[3]adelay=9712|9712[3a];[2][3a]amerge[a]" -map '[v]' -map '[a]' -c:v libx264 -preset slower -crf 0 -c:a aac -ac 2 merged.mp4
```

for the `-ss` value taken the difference in video start time and `adelay` value taken the difference in audio start time

Sample test conference files

1. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByVMq5U43FGlbXpXR3JtSnFTaWM
2. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByVMq5U43FGlbENVRWlTWktQb3M
3. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByVMq5U43FGldndlZDNpNWxWY2M
4. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByVMq5U43FGlei1oRjNKeXRZbE0

now facing audio sync issues and second audio hearing low.

Expected result is first video and second video merged side by side and audio should sync with merged video.

Now I can able to get desired output using the below command

```
ffmpeg -i first.mkv -i second.mkv -i first.mka -i second.mka -filter_complex "[0]scale=320:240,pad=645:240,setsar=1[l];[1]scale=320:240,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+9.723/TB,setsar=1[1v];[l][1v]overlay=x=325[v];[3]adelay=9712|9712[1a];[2]adelay=31|31[2a];[2a][1a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map '[v]' -map '[a]' -c:v libx264 -preset slower -crf 0 -c:a aac -ac 2 merged.mp4
```

but again facing following issues

1. Second Video not encoded properly stuck in middle and playing.
2. Audio Sync issues.
3. Conversion process is slow. how can be above work done using hstack?.

any suggestions or help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i first.mkv -i second.mkv -i 1st.wav -i 2nd.wav -filter_complex "
[0:v]scale=320:240,pad=325:240,setsar=1[l];[1:v]setpts=PTS+6/TB,scale=320:240,setsar=1[r];
[l][r]hstack=shortest=1,drawbox=325:0:c=black:t='max':enable='lt(t,6)'[v];
[3]adelay=6000|6000[3a];[2][1a]amerge[a]" -map '[v]' -map '[a]' -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 0 -c:a aac -ac 2 merged.mp4
```

---

**UPDATE**: For the current set of uploaded files, use the command below

```
ffmpeg -i first.mkv -i second.mkv -c:a libopus -i first.mka -c:a libopus -i second.mka
 -filter_complex
        "[0]fps=30,scale=320:240,pad=645:240,setsar=1[l];
         [1]fps=30,scale=320:240,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+3.981/TB,setsar=1[1v];
         [l][1v]overlay=x=325[v];
         [2]atrim=0.025,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,aresample=async=1,pan=stereo|c0=c0|c1=c1[2a];
         [3]atrim=0.012,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,aresample=async=1,adelay=3981|3981,pan=stereo|c0=c0|c1=c1[3a];
         [2a][3a]amerge=inputs=2[a]"
 -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -preset fast -crf 10 -c:a aac -ac 2 merged.mp4
```

`first.mkv` start time is 07.930 
`first.mka` start time is 07.905 
`second.mkv` start time is 11.911 
`second.mka` start time is 11.899

These audio files use codec features not implemented in ffmpeg's native Opus decoder, so external decoder is forced.

The first video file fps isn't detected so for both videos, I force the same framerate using `fps` filter.

The atrim filters are added for both audios with value equal to difference of start times between audio and corresponding video. The timestamps of the trimmed audio has to be reset us9ing `asetpts`. Any gaps in the recording have to be filled out using `aresample`. Only the late-starting a/v should have its audio `adelay`-ed, with value equal to difference of video start times. `pan` filters added to fix channel layout, required for amerge.

`preset` changed to fast. CRF increased to `10` (`0` is a large waste of space).

Comment: thanks for your help, actually the audio files are separate files which is not merged with video. There are 4 separate files 2 video files and 2 audio files respectively. please suggest to merge those files

Comment: thanks for your quick reply t='max(iw,ih)' is showing syntax error and changed to t=3 and ran code `ffmpeg -i first.mkv -i second.mkv -i 1st.wav -i 2nd.wav -filter_complex"
[0:v]scale=320:240,pad=325:240,setsar=1[l];[1:v]setpts=PTS+6/TB,scale=320:240,setsar=1[r];
[l][r]hstack=shortest=1,drawbox=325:0:c=black:t=3:enable='lt(t,6)'[v];
[3]adelay=6000|6000[3a];[2][3a]amerge[a]" -map '[v]' -map '[a]' -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 0 -c:a aac -ac 2 merged.mp4`and output shows both video paused for 6 s and start over but audio starts from beginning no backbox added at the beginning of 2 video

Comment: put a \ after iw. t cannot be 3. Share the full console output.

Comment: console output `[Parsed_amerge_9 @ 0x3631c80] No channel layout for input 1
[Parsed_amerge_9 @ 0x3631c80] Input channel layouts overlap: output layout will be determined by the number of distinct input channels
[Parsed_drawbox_7 @ 0x3660d80] [Eval @ 0x7ffd62a61970] Invalid chars '(iw,ih)' at the end of expression 'max(iw,ih)'
    Last message repeated 5 times
[Parsed_drawbox_7 @ 0x3660d80] Error when evaluating the expression 'max(iw,ih)'.
[Parsed_drawbox_7 @ 0x3660d80] Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_drawbox_7
Error configuring complex filters.
Invalid argument`

Comment: Edited command. There's a literal called 'max' which is defined, causing a parse error. Will get that changed.

Comment: added detailed description. Please help in this

Comment: Can you share the media materials?

Comment: added sample media materials. please help in this

Comment: How can sync be verified? The videos are pointing at some fabric. For lip-sync or other diegetic sounds, we need to be able to see the visual of the sound producer.

Comment: added test conference video call files. please help in this.

Comment: added command using pad and overlay, mentioned the issues faced. please help in this.

Comment: Great answer. You just made my day

Comment: instead of using -ac 2 for stereo output i need to do with pan filter is it possible or how to avoid below warning `[Parsed_amerge_13 @ 0x37d27c0] Input channel layouts overlap: output layout will be determined by the number of distinct input channels
[Parsed_pan_9 @ 0x37da5c0] Pure channel mapping detected: 0 1
[Parsed_pan_12 @ 0x37e5020] Pure channel mapping detected: 0 1`. Due to this audio is muted after conversion at some point and then normal. please help in this.@Mulvya