# Dividing multiple numbers with a variable in bash

Tags: bash, floating-point, integer

I need to calculate the area of a circle if the user inputs the circumference.
This is what I have, but it's not working:

```
let radius=$circumference/(2*3.1415)
```

and

```
let area=3.1415*$radius*$radius
```

Comment: `bash` cannot do floating point arithmetic. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722095/how-do-i-use-floating-point-division-in-bash).

Comment: Why are you dividing by π to immediately multiply by π? The area of a circle is half of the circumference times the radius (just look at it like a triangle, it's the same formula).

Answer (score 2):

As the comment pointed out, bash won't do floats. I'd try a simple `echo+bc` solution, but you can use `awk` and others as well.

```
radius=$(echo $circumference/\(2*3.1415\) | bc -l)
```

and

```
area=$(echo 3.1415*$radius*$radius | bc -l)
```

not elegant or particularly portable, but it works.

Edit: I created a `test.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash

circumference=4

radius=$(echo $circumference/\(2*3.1415\) | bc -l)

area=$(echo 3.1415*$radius*$radius | bc -l)

echo $radius $area
```

and when I do `bash test.sh` on the terminal I get:

```
.63663854846410950183 1.27327709692821900365
```

Comment: It's better to use `$(cmd)` instead of `\`cmd\``, check this [Bash FAQ #82](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082). And just a nitpick, you can also use redirection instead of `echo`: `bc -l <<< "3.1415*$radius*$radius"`.

Comment: im getting a syntax error whenever I run the script

Comment: Did you just copy/paste the above? Also, are you using `bash`? I'll add a small script to the answer above, and you can try that.