# How to sum reciprocals in bash?

Tags: bash, addition

I am attempting to find the sum of a list of numbers' reciprocals. To illustrate what I am trying to do, here's a basic example:

With the file:

```
1  
2  
3  
4
```

I would be trying to find the sum of `1/1`, `1/2`, `1/3` and `1/4`. Is there a simple `bash` one-liner to do this? (I am new to `bash`, so explanations would be welcome!)

Comment: This question has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12722107/5411198 . You can't do floating point arithmetic only with bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
sed 's|^|1/|' file | paste -sd+ | bc -l
```

- `sed 's|^|1/|'` prepends `1/` to every line
- `paste -sd+` joins all lines with a plus sign creating an arithmetic expression `1/1+1/2+1/3+1/4`
- `bc -l` evaluates that arithmetic expression and outputs the result

Comment: How does it work? I know, but the OP probably doesn't.

Comment: @choroba you are right, added explanation :)

Comment: @mickp - Thank you very much! I hadn't thought to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an arithmetical progression, you can use this `bash` one-liner using the `bc` command

```
d=0; for c in {1..4}; do d=`echo "$d + 1/$c" | bc -l`; done; echo "$d"
```

Its output is `1 + 0.5 + 0.3333 + 0.25` =

```
2.08333333333333333333
```

It works by

1. Setting a variable named `d` to `0`
2. Creating a `for` loop that counts from 1 to 4
3. In the `for` loop it sets the `d` variable to the new value `$d + 1/$c` passed to the `bc -l` command executing the arithmetic
4. And outputs the value with an `echo` command