# arithmatic operation in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, awk, programming-pearls

My shell script look like this ,

```
sOneCount =5
sZeroCount=12
aa=`expr $sOneCount / $sZeroCount`
successRate=`expr $aa \* 100
```

since 5/12 results in 0.416 and then 0.416*100 it should give 41.6
but i am getting  "successRate"  as 0.
Its rounding off the float value.

I want the final result should be 41 like this,
please help me in this Thanks

Comment: yes, `awk` will simplify this. Please read at least [Awk Tutorial -- printf](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-27) and the **Format Specifiers** section below. Good luck.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that you are using a Bourne-style shell that does not support the standard POSIX arithmetic expression. Use `aa=$(( sOneCount / sZeroCount ))` and `successRate=$(( aa * 100 ))` instead. `expr` is obsolete except for regular-expression matching. (But more to the point, most shells don't support floating-point arithmetic; `zsh` is a notable exception.)

Comment: You can find quite comperhensive list of solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722095/how-do-i-use-floating-point-division-in-bash

Answer (score 2):

Bash, and probably other similar shells, doesn't support floating point operations:

> Evaluation is done in fixed-width integers with no check for overflow

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#ARITHMETIC_EVALUATION

You can use [`bc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bc.1p.html) instead, with the mathlib operations enabled:

```
$ successRate=$(echo "${sOneCount} / ${sZeroCount} * 100" | bc -l)
$ echo ${successRate}
41.66666666666666666600
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using awk, not shell, for the calculations (and probably whatever else you're doing too but we can't see the rest of your script):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/env bash

sOneCount=$1
sZeroCount=$2

awk -v sOneCount="$sOneCount" -v sZeroCount="$sZeroCount" 'BEGIN{
    aa = (sZeroCount == 0 ? 0 : sOneCount / sZeroCount)
    successRate = aa * 100
    print successRate
    printf "%d\n", successRate
}'

$ ./tst.sh 5 12
41.6667
41

$ ./tst.sh 5 0
0
0
```

Note that it protects against a divide by zero error.

Answer (score 1):

Note in the `expr` man page<sup>(1)</sup> that the `/` operator gives you the **quotient**, implying this is interger-only arithmetic.

You can get the integral successRate by multiplying the numerator by 100 *first*

```
$ successRate=$( expr 100 \* "$sOneCount" / "$sZeroCount" )
$ echo "$successRate"
41
```

Or, in bash, you don't need to call out to expr -- use the builtin arithmetic expression syntax:

```
$ successRate=$(( 100 * sOneCount / sZeroCount ))
$ echo "$successRate"
41
```

---

(1): the man page for the BSD `expr` on my Mac is more explicit: `/` returns the result of "integer division" of "integer-valued arguments".

Answer (score 1):

You can easily write your own calculator/eval in `awk` for most basic cases

For example:

```
$ eval() { awk "BEGIN {print $1}"; }
$ x=4; y=7;
$ eval "$x/$y"
0.571429

$ rate=$(eval "$x/$y")
$ eval "$rate*100"
57.1429
```

or, with a slight change can accept more arguments

```
$ eval() { awk "BEGIN {print $*}"; }
$ eval "$x" / "$y" "*" 100
57.1429
```