# How to get the pass percentage using shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I have the below script which is trying to get the pass percentage through shell script.

**Script:**

```
  n= "$pass"/"$total";
  "$n" * = 100;
  echo "$n"
```

**Output:**

> /tmp/jenkins3601870177535319162.sh: line 45: 20/25*=: No such file or
>   directory 20/25

I'm not sure the above calculation is correct. But I just have variable $pass which is having pass test case count and $total variable which had total test case count. Just wanna get percentage of the passed test cases using shell.

Comment: **No space around** `'='`, and then `n=$((pass/total))` (no need for `$` inside `$((...))`) and then `n=$((n*100))` Also note, shell uses *integer* math. For example `n=$((20/25))` then `n -eq 0`. You can use `bc` or `awk` for floating-point math.

Comment: You can get whole numbers with `n=$(((pass * 100)/total))` Which for `pass=20` and `total=25` will result in `n=80`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use floating-point division in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722095/how-do-i-use-floating-point-division-in-bash)

Comment: David C Rankin - Many thanks. It works like charm..

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with your scripting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two primary problems: (1) there cannot be any spaces on either side of the `'='` sign; and (2) shell uses ***integer*** math so `20/25` will equal `0`.

The POSIX arithmetic operator is `((...))` where your expression goes within `((...))`. Also, within `((...))` there is no need to derefernce the variable name by preceding it with a `'$'`.

To assign the result of the expression to a variable you precede the operator by the `'$'`, e.g. `n=$((pass/total))`.

To get around the fact that shell uses ***integer*** math, you can multiply `pass` by `100` before you divide and at least get a whole-number percentage. For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

pass=20
total=25

n=$(((pass * 100)/total))

printf "pass percentage: %d\n" "$n"
```

If you run the script you will then get:

```
$ sh percent.sh
pass percentage: 80
```

Where `80%` is what would be the percent result for `20/25`. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.