# Inverse modulo operations in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash script that will be able to do inverse modulo operations.
Currently the program can do regular mod calculations but trying to do inverse modulo operations leaves me with wrong answers (either prints 0's or wrong answers).
Is it even possible to do inverse calculations, if so what would be the formula?

Expected Result:

```
28 14 22 30 18 32 30 12 25 37 8 31 18 4 37 3 33 35 27 2 4 3 28
```

Gotten Results:

```
-23 -4 -29 -27 -17 -10 -27 -25 -24 -11 -37 -5 -17 -32 -11 -15 -6 -35 -39 -22
```

```
#!/bin/bash
flag_enc=(268 413 110 190 426 419 108 229 310 379 323 373 385 236 92 96 169 321 284 185 154 137 186) #inputs

for i in "${flag_enc[@]}"
do
mod=$((1 / $i))      # input^(-1)
modus=$(($mod % 41)) #mod41 calculation
echo "$modus"
done
```

Oguz Ismail gave the right mathematical expression for calculating inverse mod in bash. I am attaching the modified the script bellow:

```
flag_enc=(268 413 110 190 426 419 108 229 310 379 323 373 385 236 92 96 169 321 284 185 154 137 186)
m=41

for i in "${flag_enc[@]}"
do
    for ((x = 1; x < m; x++)); do
    if ((($i % m) * (x % m) % m == 1)); then
      echo $x     
fi
done
done
```

Comment: Can you share more details about the inputs and the expected outputs? What do you mean by "inverse modulo"?

Comment: @NicoHaase What I mean by "inverse modulo" is inverse modular multiplicative. The inputs are in the array list called "flag_enc". With the current script my answers are zeroes or just wrong ones. Example: 268 mod 41 = 22; Inverse modulo - 268 ^ -1 mod41 = 28, the answer that I get is "-23"

Comment: This seems like a math question rather than a programming question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746028/inverse-modulo-function has some sort of solution. Implementing it in Bash seems like an odd choice.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. What **exactly** did you try to resolve the problem?

Comment: You can't do floating-point arithmetic in Bash. Easiest imho is to use zsh. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722095/how-do-i-use-floating-point-arithmetic-in-bash. Also remove the extra first for loop `for ((i = 0; i < 22 ; i++)); do`. I have no idea what that's for.

Comment: @tripleee It is a programming math questionsInverse modulo functions are a bit different than modulo operations. The inverse mod mathematical equation can be written as follows: a * x = 1 mod. I do agree that bash is a weird choice but why not.

Comment: There's also the problem that any 0,... decimal modulo an integer will give the 0,... decimal itself. Something is def off with these calculations. Consider the below run in zsh: `~/ % echo $(( 1.0 / 268))                   
0.0037313432835820895
~/ % echo $(( 0.0037313432835820895 % 41 ))   
0.0037313432835820895`

Comment: Thanks @Alex, probably because bash does not do proper floating-point arithmetic I do not get proper answers also "bc -l" does not work. I guess my best bet is to write a script w/ python.

Comment: "Why can't I use floating-point arithmetic in Bash" makes this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722095/how-do-i-use-floating-point-arithmetic-in-bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if your algorithm is correct or not, but bash doesn't support floating point arithmetic intrinsically.

So either use `bc`, or define a function like below

```
mmi() {
  a=$1
  m=$2

  for ((x = 1; x < m; x++)); do
    if (((a % m) * (x % m) % m == 1)); then
      echo $x
      return 0
    fi
  done

  return 1
}
```

and use it like so:

```
$ mmi 268 41
28
```

Comment: Thanks! This will work perfectly. I did not know how to write the mathematical expression correctly and will keep in mind that bash does not do floating point arithmetics

Answer (score 1):

Better use a dedicated tool or programming language. Example with the `gmpy2` module of `python` (without error handling, this is left as an exercise):

```bash
for i in "${flag_enc[@]}"; do
  mod=$(printf 'import gmpy2\nprint(int(gmpy2.invert(%d, %d)))\n' "$i" "41" | python)
  echo "$mod"
done
```