# bash shell script printf decimal 3 places not working

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to print result of an expression to 3 decimal places using the below code. it always prints like 5.000 instead of like 5.343. is there something wrong .

```
number=$((5+50*3/20 + (19*2)/7))
 
printf "%.3f \n" $number
```

Comment: Works for me... how do you assign the number? And what's your locale (output of `locale`)?

Comment: How is the `number` assigned?

Comment: This isn't complete enough to be testable unless you include a specific value for `number` in the question itself. (If it turns out that `number` is incorrectly assigned, that wouldn't be surprising: anywhere you use native shell math instead of floating-point-aware tools would truncate everything after the decimal if it doesn't fail outright).

Comment: See https://ideone.com/zMlwfP as an example showing printf working as-intended. (Note `"$number"`, not `$number`; in general, _all_ expansions should be quoted unless you have a specific reason to do otherwise in the immediate context at hand).

Comment: Shell only computes integers.

Comment: The problem is not the `printf`, but the "expression", which you have not shown.  Numeric values in many context in the shell are integer only, and quite likely however you are computing the expression is one of those contexts.

Comment: sorry I have updated with expression example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use floating-point arithmetic in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722095/how-do-i-use-floating-point-arithmetic-in-bash).  As pointed out by @LéaGris, native bash does only integers.  Its not a printf issue.

Comment: it works by using bc used.